# Чи є в українській аналог англійського "must-have" на позначення чогось вкрай необхідного?

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

В сучасних англомовних текстах часто можна зустріти вираз "X is a **must have** for Y" або його скорочений варіант "X is a **must**":

- Kitchenaid Stand Mixer Still the king of stand mixers, and a [must-have](http://Kitchenaid%20Stand%20Mixer%20Still%20the%20king%20of%20stand%20mixers,%20and%20a%20must-have%20for%20anyone%20who%20bakes%20a%20lot.) for anyone who bakes a lot.

Чи є якісь схожі за структурою вирази в українській, які б дозволяли передати схожий зміст?

Comment: А можете пояснити, будь ласка, чим не влаштовує *«необхідний»*? На мою думку, англійське стале словосполучення виникло саме внаслідок відсутності такого гарного і лаконічого слова, як *«необхідний»*. Можете замислитися над етимологією: «такий, який не можна *обійти* (навколо)»

Comment: @bytebuster `necessary`, `essential` - цілком відображають ідею необхідності, але з `must have`, напевно, кращі показники продажів

Comment: @bytebuster, в англійській є немало слів, які передають ідею необхідності, як і в словниковій українській. "Must have", на мою думку, скоріше не стільки про необхідність, а от саме про моду й культуру споживання, як chizh і зауважив. Адже, наприклад, можна сказати, що щось "конче необхідно мати", чи "кров з носу потрібно". Але воно не звучить "стильно, модно, молодіжно".

Comment: Чесно кажучи, я у *must have*, у порівнянні з *essential* та *necessary*, бачу лише важливе дієслово *have*, яке несе конотацію саме володіння або придбання чогось, чого допіру не мав. Ну і — так, *«молодьожно»* :)

Comment: А ще ж є *must see*, *must read*.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, маєте рацію, але я вирішила обрати лише одну з цих фраз для запитання, бо по суті вони не відрізняються (НМД).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Через народну творчість на словотворі, де вони пропонують неологізм [кончетреба](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/mastkhev), натрапив на таку статтю з ["Як ми говоримо"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53405/33217.html):

> НЕОБХІДНИЙ, НЕОБХІДНО, НЕОБХІДНІСТЬ, ПОТРІБНИЙ, НЕОДМІННИЙ, КОНЧЕ ПОТРІБНИЙ, ДОКОНЕЧНИЙ, ТРЕБА 1, КОНЧЕ ТРЕБА, УКРАЙ ТРЕБА, АЖ-АЖ-АЖ ТРЕБА, ПОТРІБНО, ПОТРЕБА, ГОСТРА ПОТРЕБА, КОНЕЧНА ПОТРЕБА, ДОКОНЕЧНА ПОТРЕБА, НАГАЛЬНА ПОТРЕБА.

Думаю, в цьому конкретному випадку:

Kitchenaid Stand Mixer Still - король статичних міксерів, `конче потрібна` річ для всіх тих, хто багато пече.

Можна використовувати `кончетреба`, `конче треба`, `конче потрібний` (і всі можливі відмінювання) в залежності від ситуації.